# How to get Orderd product Sku

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get Orderd product Sku

```
$actparterprocost=$totalamount-$commision;
                $collectionsave=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist');
                $collectionsave->setmageproid($item->getProductId());
                $collectionsave->setmageorderid($lastOrderId);
                $collectionsave->setmagerealorderid($order->getIncrementId());
                $collectionsave->setmagequantity($qty);
                $collectionsave->setmageproownerid($seller_id);
                $collectionsave->setcpprostatus(0);
                $collectionsave->setmagebuyerid(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId());
                $collectionsave->setmageproprice($price);
                $collectionsave->setmageproname($item->getName());
                if($totalamount!=0){
                $collectionsave->settotalamount($totalamount);
                }
                else{
                $collectionsave->settotalamount($price);
                }
                $collectionsave->setTotaltax($taxamount);
                if(Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/taxmanage')){
                    $actparterprocost=$actparterprocost+$taxamount;
                }               
                $collectionsave->settotalcommision($commision);
                $collectionsave->setactualparterprocost($actparterprocost);
                $collectionsave->setcleared_at(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                $collectionsave->save();
                $qty='';


foreach ($collection as $record) {
        $i++;
            if($i<=5){
                if(count($gropoid) && $record->getmagerealorderid()==$gropoid[$i-1]){
                    $i--;
                    $productid=$productid.",".$record->getmageproid();
                    $productname=$productname.",".$record->getmageproname()." X ".$record->getmagequantity();
                    $pprice=$pprice+$record->getactualparterprocost();
                    $userorder[$i]=array('mageproid'=>$productid,
                                            'mageorderid'=>$record->getmageorderid(),
                                            'magerealorderid'=>$record->getmagerealorderid(),
                                            'mageproname'=>$productname,
                                            'actualparterprocost'=>$pprice,
                                            'cleared_at'=>$record->getcleared_at()
                                            );          
                }
                else{
                    $productname=$record->getmageproname()." X ".$record->getmagequantity();
                    $productid=$record->getmageproid();
                    $pprice=$record->getactualparterprocost();
                    $groporderid[$i]=$record->getmageorderid();
                    $gropoid[$i]=$record->getmagerealorderid();
                    $userorder[$i]=array('mageproid'=>$record->getmageproid(),
                                        'mageorderid'=>$record->getmageorderid(),
                                        'magerealorderid'=>$record->getmagerealorderid(),
                                        'mageproname'=>$productname,
                                        'actualparterprocost'=>$pprice,
                                        'cleared_at'=>$record->getcleared_at()
                                        );          
                }   
            }
        }


foreach($_collection as $res){
            $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid']);
            $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$res['mageproname']."</a> X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."&nbsp;</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `$products->getSku()`

```
foreach($_collection as $res){
                $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid']);
                $name = $name."<p style='float:left;'><a href='".Mage::getUrl($products->getUrlPath())."' target='blank'>".$res['mageproname']."</a> ".$products->getSku()." X ".intval($res['magequantity'])."&nbsp;</p>";
    }
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$products'

Comment: updated answer check and feedback

Comment: It get base product sku only some assign product have custom sku also how to get that

Comment: custom sku attribute code name?

Comment: try `$products->getYOURATRIBUTECODE()` you will get that too

Comment: that also sku but table only different

Comment: I want to check if product assign some seller that seller sku will display otherwise base sku will display

Comment: you have to give me some additional information on that to write the query

Comment: let us assume 1 product have more then one seller, Each seller have differen sku. So that i want to correct sku
assign product sku store different table

Comment: Post new question with table detail and sellers relationship with product and also with order

Comment: Ok thans how to restrict product name here

Comment: Sorry don't get you can u explain little more

Comment: here i got a product name how to restict character length

Comment: Use php substr function . I can't give you code. I am on mobile

Comment: ok not a problem i got solution can u plz check this your free time http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96465/call-to-a-member-function-getid-on-a-non-objec?noredirect=1#comment129358_96465

Answer (score 2):

> Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection'); retrieves collection of orders (sales_flat_order)

SKU is stored in sales_flat_order_item

From order you can get order items using method getAllVisibleItems (it will retrieve respective sales_flat_order_item) see the definition in `Mage_Sales_Model_Order`

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
foreach($orders as $order){
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    foreach($items as $item){
        $sku = $item->getSku();
    }
}
```

The point is like that, you have to modify it by yourself. For the money spent on each item, you can also take a look at sales_flat_order_item

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: I know this i am asking above collection how to print sku

Comment: just print_r($sku); you will get array or skus.

Comment: Where i have to use

Comment: after you get $sku in template or $item->getSku() after that.