# Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in price.php file

Tags: magento-1.9

I got **Fatal error** in my website

: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in `price.php` file

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable/Price.php
```

I don't know what is the problem for this.

Comment: We're going to need more details before we can help you. Can you provide a trace of this error?

Comment: what you thing u need

Comment: We need a backtrace of the error. Typically, if you are looking at an exception report, it will be included. If you do not have one, you can get it by temporarily placing the PHP function `debug_backtrace()` on the line that is throwing the error.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16942701/getid-on-a-non-object